# remove element with click on outer element in window with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want, That user click on input type="checkbox", "textarea" is displayed.
then when user click on anywhere except same "textarea",  same "textarea" is hidden.
please help me that do this work.
If you have a suggestion for solving this problem, thank you for letting me know.
Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
var requiredDescription = document.querySelectorAll(".required-description");      
requiredDescription.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(){            
        item.classList.toggle('active');            
    });        

});
window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
          var desText = document.querySelector('input.active');
          if (event.target !== desText) {
              description.classList.remove('show');                            
          }
      });
```

```css
.items{
    border: 1px solid var(--txt);
    padding: .5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

p > span.label{
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
}

p > span.label-items{
    width: 70%;
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: space-between;
}

p > span.label-items > lable.label-item{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    width: 100%;
}

.description{
    border: 2px solid var(--c2);
    background-color: #e6eef7;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: none;
}

p > span.label-items > label.label-item > input.active ~ .description{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="items">
   <span class="label">example1</span>
   <span class="label-items">
      <label class="label-item" for="Others">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Others" id="Others" class="required-description">
         Others
        <textarea class="description" placeholder="Define who" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>                                            
     </label>
   </span>                                    
</p>

<p class="items">
   <span class="label">example2</span>
   <span class="label-items">
       <label class="label-item" for="Yes">
          <input type="checkbox" name="Yes" id="Yes" class="required-description">
          Yes
          <textarea class="description" placeholder="Explain more" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
       </label> 
   </span>
</p>

<p class="items">
    <span class="label">example3</span>
    <span class="label-items">
      <label class="label-item" for="ok">
         <input type="checkbox" name="ok" id="ok" class="required-description">
         Yes
          <textarea class="description" placeholder="Define" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
     </label> 
    </span>
                                    
                                    
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add click event to *body* element and check the element which is clicked to remove the class.

You can try the following way:

```js
var requiredDescription = document.querySelectorAll(".required-description");      
requiredDescription.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(){            
        item.classList.toggle('active');            
    });        
});
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e){
   if(!(e.target.nodeName == 'SPAN' || e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' || e.target.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA')){ 
requiredDescription.forEach(item => {
       item.classList.remove('active');
       document.querySelectorAll(":checked").forEach(function(chk){
        chk.checked = false;
       });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.items{
    border: 1px solid var(--txt);
    padding: .5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

p > span.label{
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
}

p > span.label-items{
    width: 70%;
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: space-between;
}

p > span.label-items > lable.label-item{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    width: 100%;
}

.description{
    border: 2px solid var(--c2);
    background-color: #e6eef7;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: none;
}

p > span.label-items > label.label-item > input.active ~ .description{
    display: block;
}


I want, That user click on input type="checkbox", "textarea" is displayed. then when user click on anywhere except same "textarea", same "textarea" is hidden. please help me that do this work. If you have a suggestion for solving this problem, thank you for letting me know. Thank you in advance for your cooperation.
```

```html
<p class="items">
   <span class="label">example1</span>
   <span class="label-items">
      <label class="label-item" for="Others">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Others" id="Others" class="required-description">
         Others
        <textarea class="description" placeholder="Define who" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>                                            
     </label>
   </span>                                    
</p>

<p class="items">
   <span class="label">example2</span>
   <span class="label-items">
       <label class="label-item" for="Yes">
          <input type="checkbox" name="Yes" id="Yes" class="required-description">
          Yes
          <textarea class="description" placeholder="Explain more" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
       </label> 
   </span>
</p>

<p class="items">
    <span class="label">example3</span>
    <span class="label-items">
      <label class="label-item" for="ok">
         <input type="checkbox" name="ok" id="ok" class="required-description">
         Yes
          <textarea class="description" placeholder="Define" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
     </label> 
    </span>
                                    
                                    
</p>
```

Comment: hello my friend, After the user fills in the 'textarea' and goes to the next section or clicks on the body, the input check box is unchecked. Is it possible for the checked to remain?